# Efficient way to test if a string is substring of any in a list of strings

Tags: java, time-complexity, string-comparison

I want to know the best way to compare a string to a list of strings. Here is the code I have in my mind, but it's clear that it's not good in terms of time complexity.

```
for (String large : list1) {
    for (String small : list2) {
        if (large.contains(small)) {
            // DO SOMETHING
        } else {
            // NOT FOR ME
        }
    }

    // FURTHER MANIPULATION OF STRING 
}
```

Both lists of strings can contain more than thousand values, so the worst case complexity can rise to 1000×1000×length which is a mess. I want to know the best way to perform the task of comparing a string with a list of strings, in the given scenario above.

Comment: It's not clear. what is the variable s. it looks like you are comparing a String `s` to a list of list of strings.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I forgot to edit that s. My bad.

Comment: @SyedDanishAli I reworded your question for clarity - I hope this this okay. Please reread it to make sure it still reflects what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
 for (String small : list2) {
    if (set1.contains(small)) {
        // DO SOMETHING
    } else {
        // NOT FOR ME
    }
}
```

set1 should be the larger list of String, and instead of keeping it as a `List<String>`, use a `Set<String>` or a `HashSet<String>`

Comment: This solution is incorrect. `String.contains()` is different from `Set.contains()`.

Comment: He wants to do a set.contains from what it sounds in the question

Comment: Yes. I got the point. Set has this functionality in Java. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @NayukiMinase consider the second list as a Set. All left to do is check the occurrence by `secondList.contains("this")`. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the first answer by sandeep. Here is the solution:

```
List<String> firstCollection = new ArrayList<>();
Set<String> secondCollection = new HashSet<>();

//POPULATE BOTH LISTS HERE.

for(String string: firstCollection){
    if(secondCollection.contains(string)){
        //YES, THE STRING IS THERE IN THE SECOND LIST
    }else{
        //NOPE, THE STRING IS NOT THERE IN THE SECOND LIST
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is, unfortunately, a difficult and messy problem. It's because you're checking whether a small string is a *substring* of a bunch of large strings, instead of checking that the small string is *equal* to a bunch of large strings.

The best solution depends on exactly what problem you need to solve, but here is a reasonable first attempt:

In a temporary place, concatenate all the large strings together, then construct a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) on this long concatenated string. With this structure, we should be able to find all the substring matches of any given `small` among all the `large` quickly.